# QueryDsl BooleanBuilder: How to create a predicate that compares another field?

Tags: java, sql, querydsl, boolean-expression

I have simple example: to find all items that are sold out.

Item has initialQuantity and soldQuantity integer fields.
(for some reason I need initialQuantity stored)

I'm trying to do something like:

```java
builder = new BooleanBuilder();
Predicate predicate = builder.and(item.initialQuantity.eq(item.soldQuantity)).getValue();
Iterable<Item> iterable = itemRepository.findAll(predicate);
```

but it does not return as expected. ".eq()" looks like it expects an integer and not Path<>

Comment: What type hast the variable item? Is it a generated Q* class? If yes, please show the specification of the corresponding database table (i assume the name is item).

Comment: Yes there is QItem. and this query works just fine if i use .eq(10) or something but I want to compare to another column in the table, how do I do this?

Comment: If `initialQuantity`  and `soldQuantity`  has the type `com.querydsl.core.types.dsl.NumberPath` it should work. Without more information (error, code, db scheme) this question does not make sense.

Comment: so there is no error, i am just not getting the value that I expected to get. I even tried builder.and(item.initialQuantity.eq(item.initialQuantity)) which should always return true, but nothing gets returned from using this query...

Comment: `builder.and(item.initialQuantity.eq(item.initialQuantity))`this is only a part of your query... what is the rest?

Comment: That is all basically. I've updated the code snippet, I'm isolating this basic query.

Comment: please show the implementation of `itemRepository.findAll`

Comment: I'm using MongoRepository : http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/repository/MongoRepository.html

Comment: see my answer... does it help?

Answer (score 1):

First declare it :

```
JPAQueryFactory query = new JPAQueryFactory(em);
BooleanBuilder booleanBuilder = new BooleanBuilder();
QCreditRequest creditRequest = QCreditRequest.creditRequest;
```

Then, you can include your business logique, for example :

```
booleanBuilder.and(creditRequest.creditRequestId.eq(dataRequest.getCreditRequestId()));

if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(dataRequest.getProductId())){
                 booleanBuilder.and(creditRequest.product.productId.eq(dataRequest.getProductId()));}
```

finally return the result, mapped to your DTO :

```
return new HashSet<>(
            query
                .select(
                    Projections.constructor(
                        APResponse.class,
                        creditRequest.creditRequestId,
                        creditRequest.creditRequestDate,
                        creditRequest.product.productId,
                        creditRequest.creditRequestComment))
                .from(creditRequest)
                .innerJoin(creditRequest.product, product)
                .innerJoin(creditRequest.status, creditRequestStatus)
                .where(booleanBuilder)
                .fetch());
```