# How do I create a JPARepository method that filter my search based on the arguments I gave it?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, filter, repository

To make it more clear and understandable. Let's say I have User entity,which has name,secondname and email params. Let's even say that in the front end I have a form that filters my search based on these params(name,secondname,email) but I can chose to leave some of them blank if I want,or to fill them all. What should my backend look like to handle something like this?

```
@Query(
        value = "SELECT * FROM utenti u WHERE"
                 + " u.nome = :nome"
                 + "AND u.cognome = :cognome"
                 + "AND u.codice_fiscale = :codiceFiscale"
                )
public List<Utente> findByFilter(
        @Param("nome") String nome,
        @Param("cognome") String cognome,
        @Param("codiceFiscale")String codiceFiscale);
```

}

I was tryng to write the query and I though about closing each "AND x = :x" in an if(x!='') statement but I don't think that's even possible,any ideas?

Comment: Have a look at Spring Data JPA Specifications (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#specifications and https://reflectoring.io/spring-data-specifications/) or Query by Example (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example and https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-query-by-example)

Comment: There are multiple ways to do this, each with its own upsides and downsides, but you have a problem here that there is no space before your `AND` keywords that will result in errors on two fronts. Be careful with that, as the first error you will get is that there is no such parameter `nome`

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this such as BooleanBuilder of QueryDsl, you can make your repository extends a custom interface (refer this [link](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-composable-repositories)), and then use BooleanBuilder to build the predicate.

- Read section 2 of this [link](https://www.baeldung.com/querydsl-with-jpa-tutorial) to add querydsl to spring boot.
- Run install in maven life cycle (in intellij you can see maven tool in the top-right corner) to produce some class QEntity (Entity is the name of your entity class).
- Write funciton to query data, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36213765/querydsl-booleanbuilder-how-to-create-a-predicate-that-compares-another-field)